# Concatenating row values sql server 2008 r2

Tags: sql-server-2008, concatenation, rows

I have two tables `register` and `att_bottom` and I want to display only the students at a certain building who have been tardy based on today's date with the periods separated by a comma.
This is the way the data is displayed when joining both tables:

```
 Student ID |  Building | Period | Grade 

   12345          2         1       11        
   12345          2         5       11
   43210          2         1       12
```

I want this:

```
Student ID | <u>Building | Period | Grade

12345          2         1,5     11
43210          2         1       12
```

This is my query:

```
 select r.STUDENT_ID,
        r.BUILDING ,
        (select ab.attendancePeriod + ','
        from att_bottom ab
        where ab.STUDENT_ID = r.student_id
        and ab.building = '2'
        and ab.attendance_c ='T'
        and ab.SCHOOL_YEAR =2014
        CONVERT(date,ab.attendance_date,102) = convert(date,getdate(),102)  
        FOR XML PATH ('') ) AS PERIODS,
        r.GRADE
        FROM register r
    where r.CURRENT_STATUS = 'A' 
    and r.BUILDING ='2'
```

I'm getting all the students at building 2 and even if they don't have an attedance_c of T; a NULL value for Periods is being retrieved:

```
Student ID | Building  | Period | Grade 

12345          2        1 , 5    11
43210          2        1  ,     12
95687          2        NULL     09
78417          2        NULL     10
20357          2        NULL     11
```

I have tried  `and ab.attendancePeriod is Not NULL` and I still get the same results.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What `DataType` you are using for your `Period`  column ??

Comment: I get three rows with that query, not 5 (after I correct syntax errors). Can you please double-check how you are getting those results? (e.g. where did 95687, 78417 etc. come from - do they simply exist in register but not in att_bottom?)

Comment: The numbers are random id's that I used to illustrate the problem.

Comment: Well we can't solve "random numbers" - can you show the source table data *before* the join?

Comment: In the table (att_bottom), the attendancePeriod column is type char(n)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The outer query doesn't listen to any filters in the subquery; it will return NULL for any rows that aren't matched by the join conditions. You need to filter differently. Here is one way (this also eliminates the errant trailing comma, and avoids comparing dates by converting them expensively to strings):

```
;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT DISTINCT s = r.Student_ID, r.building,
    p = ab.attendancePeriod, r.grade
  FROM dbo.Register AS r
  INNER JOIN dbo.att_bottom AS ab
  ON r.Student_ID = ab.Student_ID
  AND r.building = ab.building
  WHERE ab.building = '2'
  AND ab.attendance_c = 'T'
  AND ab.SCHOOL_YEAR = 2014
  AND ab.attendance_date >= CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())
  AND ab.attendance_date < DATEADD(DAY, 1, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()))
  AND r.building = '2'
  AND r.CURRENT_STATUS = 'A'
)
SELECT DISTINCT 
  [Student ID] = x.s, 
  x.building,
  Period = STUFF((SELECT ',' + x2.p FROM x AS x2 WHERE x2.s = x.s
    FOR XML PATH(''), 
    TYPE).value(N'./text()[]',N'nvarchar(max)'),1,1,''), 
  x.grade
 FROM x;
```

Another way:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT 
   r.Student_ID, 
   r.building, 
   Period = STUFF(b.p.value(N'./text()[1]', N'nvarchar(max)'),1,1,''), 
   r.grade
 FROM dbo.Register AS r
 CROSS APPLY 
 (
   SELECT p = ',' + ab.attendancePeriod
     FROM dbo.att_bottom AS ab
     WHERE ab.building = '2' 
     AND ab.attendance_c = 'T'
     AND ab.SCHOOL_YEAR = 2014
     AND ab.attendance_date >= CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())
     AND ab.attendance_date < DATEADD(DAY, 1, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()))
     AND ab.student_id = r.student_id 
     AND ab.building = r.building
     FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
 ) AS b(p)
 WHERE b.p IS NOT NULL
  AND r.building = '2'
  AND r.CURRENT_STATUS = 'A';
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the AS PERIODS select to be an inner join to r.